# Draw on Android video and save

Tags: android, ios, video, ffmpeg, media

I am a beginner to the Android meida programming, so if I have any problem please tell me, thank you very much.

Recentally, I saw an IOS version App called [V1 Sports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5hrBCiqfPA)! it allows you to record a video and then draw lines, circles or any shapes on the video. Those shapes are stored, next time when you open your video, the shapes are still there, unless you clear the shapes overlay on the video.

I am wondering how to implement those functions on an **Android** deveice, it is so cool. Use **ffmpeg** or something like that? I do not know where to start. Please tell me some hints~~ Thank you very much.

Comment: hey follow that answer it will help you...[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665201/extract-modify-video-frames-on-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665201/extract-modify-video-frames-on-android)

Comment: @sud could you provide some example or source code? Because I did the research whole night, but did not find some example of painting on video

Answer (score 0):

**Option A:**

You can create a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) object and attach this to the MediaPlayer as follows

```
myPlayer = new MediaPlayer
...
myRedirectionSurface = new Surface(mySurfaceTexture);
myPlayer->setSurface(myRedirectionSurface);
```

This way, the player's decoded stream is "redirected" to SurfaceTexture and not the SurfaceView.
The OnFrameAvailableListener is called whenever you have a decoded frame available.
To access/modify the image, you can use the Surface's lock/unlock methods on 
myRedirectionSurface.

IMPORTANT NOTE: You need to have API level 14 support to get this working !

**Option B:**

As you have indicated likelihood of using ffmpeg, you can achieve what you intend to, as you have full access to the decoder's output frames.
You can start with RockPlayer's or MoboPlayer's ffmpeg port.
But in this option, rendering the video output from NDK is not staright-forward. !

reference credits->[Extract/modify video frames on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665201/extract-modify-video-frames-on-android)